# How to write query to display all product?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to update all products price. For that I want to fetch all records and then later on update the product in Magento.

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($product_collection as $product) {

    $new_price = $product->getPrice(); // Update price here.

    $product->setPrice($new_price)
           ->save();
}
```

This will help you to update the price of all products..